# VBA Pop-up Message Code

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out how to display a pop-up if the value in a cell exceeds a certain value.

I have a worksheet that tracks the absences of employees per day. The names are in column A while the dates are in rows D to AH. I have a formula in D15 that counts the absences of employees on say D33 to D50.

What I'm looking for is a code to display a message box if the value of cell D15 exceeds 4. Then have the pop message applied from D15 to AH15. Then I want to restrict the message per cell. I also need to have it set up for E16 to AH16.

Then how do I apply it for each month but all in the same worksheet?

Comment: Your questions are too broad - there are about 4 questions in there. SO isn't a code provider. The serious users do their research, try some code and when it doesn't work, they post a question here. So show us what you've tried and where it has problems or breaks and we'll try to help.

Comment: `"What I'm looking for is a code"` I would recommend a freelancing site if you want the code written. You can pay a fair price and you'll get good code in return. Alternatively, please show us what you have tried, the relevant code and the **specific** issues you are having. Read up on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and have a look at the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on here. Then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25955453/edit) your question and give all the necessary details.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it 2 ways at least:

1. Use VBA: Add the on worksheet change event to the worksheet (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775(v=office.15).aspx) and add an if statement to check the changes in the cells you need e.g. D15. In response show the message. This has 1 setback - you will not be able to do CTRL+Z (undo) operations as when VBA executes it cancels the log of modified operations.
2. Simply add a column with a formula asserting the condition in D15. In response may the formula simply show text with the message. You can also use conditional formatting to change the cell background (e.g. to red).